# Transporting lots of luggage at Luton airport

Tags: air-travel, luggage, london

I'll be travelling from Luton airport next month, with a large amount of luggage, far too much for an ordinary luggage trolley.

I'm sure I'm not the first person to have had this problem! Does Luton airport have concierge services or, better, larger luggage trolleys for hire? Or can you recommend an alternative solution?

Comment: As a single traveler? This means you're probably paying the airline **a lot** in charges for the extra luggage. There may be other (possible cheaper, and more convenient since they could provide door-to-door service) alternatives like shipping that stuff instead of transporting it on the flight.

Comment: @jcaron A door to door service would be ideal. However, the cost of an extra suitcase is about £50 if booked in advance. The cheapest quote for a door to door service that I’ve found is £250+ per suitcase. I’ve looked into Royal Mail, ups, fedex, etc, but I’m open to suggestions!

Comment: We’re missing quite a few parameters here, including the number of suitcases, their size and weight, where from, and how fast you need them. I found prices under 50 euros per piece for a 25 kg package measuring 80 x 50 x 28 from Paris to London for instance.

Comment: As you say you looked at Royal Mail I suppose this is from the UK... UPS from Glasgow to London for the same size package can be as low as £12! So either you are shipping from quite a distance further, or there’s something specific about your package, and then you would probably have an issue having it on the flight?

Comment: @jcaron Luton airport was also a giveaway that this is from the UK :). My understanding is that for international shipping of 23kg boxes/suitcases, taking the luggage with you is almost always significantly cheaper than shipping it.

Answer (score 6):

They do in fact offer a [Porter Service](https://murgencyairportassistance.com/ourservices?c=llt), BUT it comes in a package with many other perks:

> **Baggage handling Services**
>
> Porter service includes collecting luggage from your vehicle to the check-in counter. Please notify the number of baggage while making the booking. (An extra fee may apply for porter service at certain airports.)

You'll have to go through a sign up process before they reveal the price (yikes I'm sure).

[Royal Airport Concierge](https://www.royalairportconcierge.com/luton-ltn-airport-vip-service) also offers this service at Luton.

As for your question:

> Does Luton airport have concierge services or, better, larger luggage trolleys for hire?

From my experience I haven't seen any, and there is no indication of larger trolleys being available to the public.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For the reference of future readers, I contacted the first link. They want $350 for the package, which includes help with luggage, but porter services are extra!

Answer (score 2):

You could get a man and van hire company to drive you there and help unload and get the luggage into the airport. To them it won't make much difference whether they're carrying moving boxes and furniture or suitcases. In fact, suitcases are easier to carry. If there's two of you, you can use two trolleys easily.

Most of these companies charge per the hour, anywhere from around 20 to 50 GBP per hour. They are usually meant for moving and removals, but I'm sure they'll take an easy job such as this. You can offer to pay for the parking too.

I've googled "Luton Man and Van" and went on [the first non-add link here](http://www.manvanluton.co.uk/prices/). This is 30 GBP per hour for one man and one van, two hours minimum.

Or you could get a large taxi/uber and offer the driver 10 or 20 GBP cash to help you carry all the stuff inside.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, this is probably the best answer to the question – I'm still somewhat surprised that an airport that handles thousands of passengers per day has no porter service! (In the end, I'm going to bribe a family member to come along and help and pay for their transport home.)

Comment: @A-W remember it's Luton. If you go to Heathrow, you can probably get everything there. But Luton... I've only had one return flight from there and it was not a pleasant experience. Some large bus stations have more amenities.

Comment: Just had a look to see what Heathrow offers. Got an instant quote for £20 for everything I'd need. Good to know for the future!